# How to create a liquidity pool on Raydium on Solana devnet?

Tags: swap, solana

Can anyone give me any advice on how to create an LP pool on the Solana devnet?

I planned this job for testing swaps between specific two tokens on the devnet using the Raydium protocol.

So, I need to create a swap pool on the devnet first.
To achieve this, I did it like below.

First of all, to list on the serum market, I cloned the Raydium-Dex repository on my mac and changed the Serum dex's program id from the mainnet to the devnet, and I success registered on the devnet serum. (Custom token with SOL pairs)
As a result, I got a serum market program id.

After that, I cloned the Raydium-frontend repository to create a liquidity pool. And modified `wellknownToken.config.ts` so that my custom tokens could be possible to create a new pool.

Finally, I could access the create pool UI from the localhost web UI.
I clicked Initialize Liquidity Pool button on the UI and got a Toast message `Create a new pool Transaction Sent` apparently.

However, It is not worked well. Because I can not find the transaction hash on the Solscan website.
I tracked the button's click event codes and I figured out one thing.

One of the result value of `Liquidity.makeCreatePoolTransaction` function has a null value, especially, feePayer.

```js
const { transaction: sdkTransaction1, signers: sdkSigners1 } = Liquidity.makeCreatePoolTransaction({
        poolKeys: sdkAssociatedPoolKeys,
        userKeys: { payer: owner }
})
const testTx = await loadTransaction({ transaction: sdkTransaction1, signers: sdkSigners1 })
console.log('feepayer', testTx.feePayer?.toBase58()) // null
```

I felt this is not the preferred (good) way to create a swap pool on the Solana devnet, but I can not find a better way to achieve this task.

What am I missing? or What am I should read or learn?
please give me some advice on how to do it to make it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the transaction created with `Liquidity.makeCreatePoolTransaction` hasn't been sent to the network, so it doesn't exist anywhere.  Be sure to send and confirm the transaction before trying to load it.  You can use something like:

```
const { transaction: sdkTransaction1, signers: sdkSigners1 } = Liquidity.makeCreatePoolTransaction({
        poolKeys: sdkAssociatedPoolKeys,
        userKeys: { payer: owner }
});
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet]);
```

Note that this requires a `connection` to send and a `wallet` to sign.  More info at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9ac2245970de90af30bff9d1f7f35cd2d8f2bf6d/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts#L18

You might run into other issues though, because the Raydium program isn't deployed to devnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8?cluster=devnet